# ajax, jquery sortable, order updates

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

What I wanted to achieve is to update the order of slides in the database, by changing the 'order' input's value in the overview (each row has it's own input), 
or by dragging the rows.

So I first fixed this input, and placed the ajax request in a function. This function expects the row itself and the new order value, see ajax_order(row, newval);.

Then I made the rows sortable and added a update: function to it:

```
$( ".rows-container" ).sortable();

$(".rows-container").sortable({
    update: function( ) {
        $('.rows-container').children().each(function(i, el){
            ajax_order($(this), i + 1);
            $(this).find('.overview-number').val(i+1);
        });
    }
});
```

Right now I'm looping through the rows, and using the index as the new order number. It's working fine, but every time you drag 1 row, it updates all the rows.. even if a row actualy stayed in place.

Also it might not be realy efficient if there are 30 slides saved (of which a couple might be flagged as inactive). What is a good way to do this? happy with some tips

Update:

when I added this to the function, it gives me the current (old) order when I start dragging, but also 1 extra console.log 'undefined'.. so now I have 5 console.logs and only 4 actual rows. Would be a good thing if we didn't need to track the old order or use start:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
    $('.rows-container').children().each(function(i, el){
        console.log($(this).find('.overview-number').val());
    });

},
```

Update:

So I've been puzzling all night xD zzzZZzz. Been adding php functions and removing again, adding JS objects storing old order + index and shit..tried with differend types of array in both start: and stop:

It got a big mess, so I decided to write down some scenarios on paper.. and figured a good way to go is to track the last 'order' used. Here is the result

```
$( ".rows-container" ).sortable();

$(".rows-container").sortable({

    update: function() {

        var last_val = 0;//used to compare with the next row and determine it's value
        //if the next row has lower value as the one before, it needs to become higher value
       //note that the view always gets loaded on order ASC 

        $('.rows-container').children().each(function(i){

            //the current row's order
            var current = parseInt($(this).find('.overview-number').val());

            if(i == 0 || current > last_val){ 

                if(current < last_val+5){ //row doesnt need update, yee!!!!
                    last_val = current;

                //makes sure the values dont add up too much, when the difference gets too big
                }else{
                    current = last_val+1;
                    ajax_order($(this), current);
                    $(this).find('.overview-number').val(current);
                    last_val = current;
                }

            //if the next row has lower value as the one before, it needs to become higher value
            }else if(current <= last_val){
                current = last_val+1;
                ajax_order($(this), current);
                $(this).find('.overview-number').val(current);
                last_val = current;
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Runs like a train... but as you can see there is some duplication in there, the part that runs the ajax. I've tried to put it into a function in that object and keep 'last_value' and 'current' available, but didn't succeed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the start and end position to your back-end service, and then on the server adjust records in that range. It will be more efficient that way:

```js
var initialPos, finalPos;

$("#sortable")
  .sortable()
  .on("sortstart", function( event, ui ) {
     initialPos = ui.item.index() + 1; // when using a 1-based index    
     //console.log("Item started at position", initialPos);
  })  
  .on("sortupdate", function( event, ui ) {
     finalPos =  ui.item.index() + 1; // when using a 1-based index   
     console.log(ui.item.attr('id'), "moved from position", initialPos, "to", finalPos);
    
     // call ajax function here, passing in initialPos & finalPos
     // server will need to re-order values for all elements between (and including) initialPos & finalPos
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="itm1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="itm2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="itm3">Item 3</li>
  <li id="itm4">Item 4</li>
  <li id="itm5">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm I can see where you are going, so it doesn't have to reorder the rows at ether the start or the end, before/after the row that got dragged. I think I can at least fix that.  What if I drag a row from start to end? I could keep all the rows untouched, and grab the last row's order + 1  for the row I dragged.. or is that too much trouble

Comment: Yes, the rows outside that range don't require changing. If you drag a row from any position to the very end, then sure, you can just increase its idx to the total # of rows + 1 (that's if you don't mind these values becoming non-sequential).  But in doing so, you make it harder to find the row by index value.

Comment: ... since the sequence of indexes [1,2,3,4] would then become [2,3,4,5] (when moving '1' to the last position), where as if you just re-ordered everything it would still end up as [1,2,3,4] after, and you don't have to handle a special case in your code behind of moving an element to the end

Comment: I've been trying different things and came up with something. I've edited my question. Maybe you can help me out making the code more efficient, there is some repeating code in it.

Comment: Are they stored in the DB with a numeric sort column? Your code above should all be done in the backend php. If you're not using a sequential sequence of numbers then it becomes more difficult. Why can't you use my code (perhaps use `sortupdate` where I used `sortstop` for slightly more efficiency)?

Comment: Improved code in my answer to use `sortupdate` and show the element's Id, its start, and its stop positions when dragged.

Comment: I suppose I will move the logic to the backend service tonight, what I came up with is way too slow ... new connections, scandirs etc every request..